# only run on Thonny , can't on CLI

Tags: python, terminal, raspberry-pi, command-line-interface, modulenotfounderror

I test my raspberrypi code with VNC, mobaxterm, and pycharm
its very simple code

```py
import smbus
from time import sleep

DEVICE_BUS =1
DEVICE_ADDR = 0x76

bus = smbus.SMBus(DEVICE_BUS)

while True:
    a = bus.read_byte_data(DEVICE_ADDR, 0xFA)
    b = bus.read_byte_data(DEVICE_ADDR, 0xFB)
    c = bus.read_byte_data(DEVICE_ADDR, 0xFC)
    print(a,b,c)

    result = (a<<12) | (b<<4) | ((c&0xF0) >>4)
    print(result)
    sleep(1)
```

I can run this code with Thonny in VNC
but when I run this code in CLI

'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smbus'' occurs

mobaxterm, pycharm and even in VNC terminal

how can I solve this error?

I installed and check configuration... but no use